# Django refering html path to another directory

Tags: django

I am new to Django. Just studying to render HTML pages in my app. I have an app directory named `myapp`. In that directory itself, I have created a `hello.html`. It is a simple HTML file. My view function is,

```
def hello(request):
   today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
   return render(request, "hello.html", {"today" : today})
```

When I run my page, I got the following error.

```
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/hello.html (Source does not exist)
```

I know it is referred from the wrong path. But Why it set to anaconda directory? I hope I have to change some settings? what are they?

Answer (score 0):

You should be keeping the html templates on a path like this: project_name/templates/app_name/

Answer (score 0):

edit your settings.py and set your template folder destination 
and place your hello.html in that folder

```
# Template directory setting
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),
)
```

reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/

.

Answer (score 0):

You should place **myapp** directory inside a folder named **templates** on your project directory level (See image bellow).

[Django project directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5whcf.png)

This is the default Django project structure. You can change the default directory paths by modifying **settings.py**